# PROC SUMMARY using multiple fields as a key

Tags: sas, summary

Is there a way to replicate the behaviour below using `PROC SUMMARY` without having to create the dummy variable `UniqueKey`?

```
DATA table1;
input record_desc $ record_id $ response;
informat record_desc $4. record_id $1. response best32.;
format record_desc $4. record_id $1. response best32.;
DATALINES;
  A001 1 300
  A001 1 150
  A002 1 200
  A003 1 150
  A003 1 99
  A003 2 250
  A003 2 450
  A003 2 250
  A004 1 900
  A005 1 100
;
RUN;

DATA table2;
  SET table1;
  UniqueKey = record_desc || record_id;
RUN;

PROC SUMMARY data = table2 NWAY MISSING;
  class UniqueKey record_desc record_id;
  var response;
  output out=table3(drop = _FREQ_ _TYPE_) sum=;
RUN;
```

Comment: I'm curious (as Chris is below) why you create UniqueKey?  What's the problem you're solving?

Comment: I'm thinking I must have asked the wrong question, as this one doesn't make any sense. I'm going to go look back at the code and try to work out what I didn't understand (I'm maintaining code I did not write and I remembered something odd similar to this)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial issue due to a mis-understanding of some other code. It is of no value to others. (THIS IS MY QUESTION, it cannot be salvaged)

Comment: I assume you can't delete it bc of the answer?

Comment: You can flag your question for a moderator, if you feel like it; they might delete it for you.  Or you could ping Chris below and ask him to delete his answer; both of those things would allow you to delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can summarise by record_desc and record_id (see class statement below) without creating a concatenation of the two columns.  What made you think you couldn't?

```
PROC SUMMARY data = table1 NWAY MISSING;
  class record_desc record_id;
  var response;
  output out=table4(drop = _FREQ_ _TYPE_) sum=;
RUN;


proc compare 
    base=table3
    compare=table4;
run;
```